# Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (3:0)

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeorm

Hi I'm having this issue building a Nextjs application since yesterday. I didn't made any change at this level. I have reverted changes and the error persist.

Could someone help me with that please?

---

```html
./node_modules/typeorm/browser/index.js
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders  
| /*!
|  */
> import "reflect-metadata";
| // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| // Commonly Used exports

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/typeorm/index.mjs
```

---

This is my package.json:

- I have some babel dependencies, but I don't have any .babelrc file configured, it was used for loader testing as the error message suggest, but no luck with that.

```html
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "jest --setupFiles=dotenv/config",
    "lint": "eslint pages --ext .ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.17.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.16.11",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.3.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.3.0",
    "@nivo/core": "0.74.0",
    "@nivo/line": "^0.79.1",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata": "^0.3.2",
    "bad-words": "^3.0.4",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "compressorjs": "^1.1.1",
    "date-and-time": "^2.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.2",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "next": ">=12.0.9",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-geocode": "^0.2.3",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^2.1.1",
    "react-otp-input": "^2.4.0",
    "react-simple-star-rating": "^4.0.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sass": "^1.49.0",
    "serverless-mysql": "^1.5.4",
    "swr": "^1.2.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.41",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.55",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.9.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "node-fetch": ">=2.6.7",
    "postcss": ">=8.2.13",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.7.4",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json:

```html
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@/components/*": [
          "components/*"
        ],
        "@/lib/*": [
          "lib/*"
        ],
        "@/entities/*": [
          "entities/*"
        ],
        "@/services/*": [
          "services/*"
        ]
      },
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        "esnext"
      ],
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "strict": false,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "jsx": "preserve",
      "incremental": true,
      "types": [
        "jest",
        "node"
      ]
    },
    "include": [
      "next-env.d.ts",
      "**/*.ts",
      "**/*.tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "functions"
    ]
}
```

Also I am importing typeorm not typeorm/browser as you can see:

```html
import { User } from '@/entities/User'
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { Connection, createConnection } from 'typeorm'

export async function initializeDatabase () {
  return new Promise<Connection>((resolve, reject) => {
    createConnection({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.MYSQL_PORT),
      username: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
      entities: [
        User
      ],
      synchronize: true
    }).then(connection => {
      resolve(connection)
    }).catch(error => {
      reject(error)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a Typeorm issue related to the way of managing imports from Webpack.

The issue has been mentioned [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8674)

The bug is fixed in the last commit: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/8688

Comment: Please explain the answer properly rather than just linking to solutions which don't even contain the solution.

Comment: @JuliusGoddard The solution in clearly exposed. The bug is fixed in the last commit.